# Get last instances of foreign key's

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I want to query a table and return the latest date associated to each instance of a foreign key. e.g.:

[image: Expenditure]

In other words, I want the expenditure for each project that has the highest value in `ExpenditureDate` I started of with the following query that gets the last expenditure added, but this is wrong as the last one added is not always for the latest date:

```
WITH LatestCumulativeExpenditure AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MAX(p.Id) AS Id
    FROM
        tbl_ProjectExpenditure p
    GROUP BY
        p.ProjectID
)
SELECT
    pe.Id,
    pe.ProjectID,
    pe.CumulativeMonthlyExpenditure
FROM
    tbl_ProjectExpenditure pe
    INNER JOIN LatestCumulativeExpenditure lce
        ON pe.Id = lce.Id
    INNER JOIN tbl_Project p
        ON pe.ProjectID = p.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying for the `MAX(p.Id)`, query instead for the `MAX(ExpenditureDate)`. You will need another column as well, like `ProjectID`, and to join against both columns.

```
WITH LatestCumulativeExpenditure AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        -- Get both the ProjectID and the max ExpenditureDate
        ProjectID,
        MAX(ExpenditureDate) AS maxdate
    FROM
        tbl_ProjectExpenditure
    GROUP BY
        ProjectID
)
SELECT
    pe.Id,
    pe.ProjectID,
    pe.CumulativeMonthlyExpenditure
FROM
    tbl_ProjectExpenditure pe
    INNER JOIN tbl_Project p
        ON pe.ProjectID = p.Id
    -- Join *both* columns against the primary tbl_ProjectExpenditure
    -- to match the row with that expenditure date per project Id
    INNER JOIN LatestCumulativeExpenditure lce
        ON pe.ProjectID = lce.ProjectID
        AND pe.ExpenditureDate = lce.maxdate
```

(Edit - sorry, wrong column name in the description at the top)

Comment: Oh, yes. I'd have gotten this a while ago if I'd seen that I have to join it on both the ProjectID and the datecolumn. Thanks ✓

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.ProjectID,
(
  SELECT CumulativeMonthlyExpenditure
  FROM tbl_ProjectExpenditure pe
  WHERE pe.ProjectID = p.Id
  ORDER BY ExpenditureDate DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS MAX_CumulativeMonthlyExpenditure
FROM tbl_Project p
```